# Can't turn on the rewrite engine

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have encountered a problem, while implementing MVC design patterns for my website. I have a folder named *"svce"* inside the folder `/www` (which is my `DOCUMENT_ROOT`). I created a `.htaccess` file and wrote the following codes inside it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+)$index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Then I edited the `httpd.conf` file and uncommented the `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`.

Even after doing this, `RewriteEngine` is not working. When I try to access application using `http://localhost/svce/blahblah.php`, it gives me a default 404 error page.

IT should have shown me only the index page inside the `/svce` directory.

Comment: I even restarted my apache server, I'm using wamp server

Comment: What does "MVC is not working" mean? MVC is design patter and has nothing to do with URLs or routing. And on related not: "does not work" is not a valid error message.

Comment: What are you typing into the browser?

Comment: @tereško, look at the question, I said, I wanted to implement MVC model for website, I said Im sorry if i am not able to make you understand, now please stop bugging me and help me solve this problem.

Comment: when I'm typing: `http://localhost/svce`, it displays me index page, but when I type `http://localhost/svce/nofile`, then it gives me a 404 error message.

Comment: @Bikash: This question has nothing to do with MVC. It's strictly a mod-rewrite issue.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha, ok then, if thats the case, i accept it, now what? will you please help me to solve this problem or anyone is there left to say this has nothing to do with MVC? i said im sorry.

Comment: @Bikash , [model](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5864000/727208) in MVC pattern is a layer. It is completely unrelated to any form of routing.

Comment: now i have unlinked the mvc from the question, now what? are you going to solve the problem or again i have to justify something?

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a space:

```
# here -----------v
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Without that space, the rule wants to rewrite a URI that looks like `/something/$index.phpurl=$1` and rewrite it to `[QSA,L]`, which is probably not a valid resource.

Additionally make sure you have `AllowOverride All` set in your server config.

Comment: AllowOverride All in which file? Can you please specify?

Comment: @Bikash Either in httpd.conf (server config) or in your vhost config file (which could be named any number of things, but probably ends with .conf).

Comment: if its in httpd.conf, then I have already done that, and I kept the space there, still it cant help me. I don't even get 500 error, I only get the 404 default error, i should get the index page but nothing is really helping.

Comment: @Bikash try adding `RewriteBase /` below the `RewriteEngine On`

Comment: allowoverride is set to all, rewritebase also written, .htacess file seems to be Okay restarted apache server, but can't get this thing working.

Comment: @tereško , ya i have already added the whitespace, i think apache is not responding to the .htacess file, whatever be the content on .htacess, it is not responding anything.

Comment: The file is `.htaccess` (as I twice edited in your post). With two C's.

Comment: @Bikash And you're sure there is no `AllowOverride None` inside a `<Directory>` block or anything in your config files?

Comment: no, that was mistyped, it was .htaccess sorry. its solved now